# Error compiling GCC for i686-elf on Windows(MinGW)

Tags: gcc, mingw, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile binutils and GCC (for windows) as per this [tutorial](https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler). The binutils compilation has finished without errors , however GCC has failed

**Steps I've taken**
Installed MinGW with the dependencies specified in the tutorial.
Installed the [GCC](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/) and [binutils](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/) source code and unpacked them in `$HOME/src`  folder
And in the MinGW shell:

```
export PREFIX="$HOME/opt/cross"
export TARGET=i686-elf
export PATH="$PREFIX/bin:$PATH"
```

```
cd $HOME/src
 
mkdir build-binutils
cd build-binutils
../binutils-x.y.z/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix="$PREFIX" --with-sysroot --disable-nls --disable-werror
make
make install
```

so far everything went without any errors

```
cd $HOME/src
 
# The $PREFIX/bin dir _must_ be in the PATH. We did that above.
which -- $TARGET-as || echo $TARGET-as is not in the PATH
 
mkdir build-gcc
cd build-gcc
../gcc-x.y.z/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix="$PREFIX" --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++ --without-headers
make all-gcc
make all-target-libgcc
make install-gcc
make install-target-libgcc
```

Firstly, the `which` command failed giving `unrecognized command --` . I ensured that `path_to_sysm_user/opt/cross/bin` was added to PATH and moved on
Then in `make all-gcc` warnings and errors popped up:

```
../../gcc-10.3.0/gcc/mem-stats.h:215:72: warning: ISO C++11 does not support the 'I64' ms_printf length modifier [-Wformat=]

../../gcc-10.3.0/gcc/pretty-print.c: In function 'void eat_esc_sequence(HANDLE, int, const char*, const char*)':
../../gcc-10.3.0/gcc/pretty-print.c:530:22: error: 'COMMON_LVB_UNDERSCORE' was not declared in this scope
        attrib_add |= COMMON_LVB_UNDERSCORE;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../gcc-10.3.0/gcc/pretty-print.c:539:22: error: 'COMMON_LVB_REVERSE_VIDEO' was not declared in this scope
        attrib_add |= COMMON_LVB_REVERSE_VIDEO;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../gcc-10.3.0/gcc/pretty-print.c:644:24: error: 'COMMON_LVB_REVERSE_VIDEO' was not declared in this scope
       if (attrib_add & COMMON_LVB_REVERSE_VIDEO)
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

# And it finished with

make[1]: *** [pretty-print.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/Ashok/src/build-gcc/gcc'
make: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
```